# How to do USB mode switch on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, modem, usb-modeswitch

I am working on LTE USB modem driver installation.

While plugin USB device it detect as CD-ROM and we need to switch it to USB modem before installing windows modem driver on the device.

How does one go about executing a USB switch mode on Windows?.

I found it can be done using `DeviceIOControl()  IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`. But I am unclear as to  what values need to passed in struct `SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`.

Is there any other method to do USB mode switch ?

Otherwise, what values need to pass in scsi ioctl?

Comment: The contents of structure would be device specific. You'll have to ask the manufacturer of the device.

Comment: Is there any other method which is common to all devices.